# RViz is not working properly and showing extra joint

Tags: ros2, rviz, urdf

this is the urdf file that i am using in RViz

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

```
<material name="blue">
    <color rgba="0.0 0.0 0.5 1.0"/>
</material>

<material name="grey">
    <color rgba="0.0 0.5 0.5 1.0"/>
</material>

<link name="B">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.6 0.4 0.2"/>
        </geometry>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.1" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <material name="blue"/>
    </visual>
</link>
```

I don't know why is "" and "" is not showing in the file but I am getting this output

[image]

using this command

```
ros2 launch urdf_tutorial display.launch.py model:=shitbot.urdf
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the problem is that urdf file is to create a single box without any joints buts its ending up as this.

Comment: I got the solution. I don’t know how but if I turn off the network, it’s works perfectly. Also I was using urdf_tutorial for the launch command as I was just learning bout the urdf files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give more details, if you are making your own package. If yes, then you need to write your own launch file accordingly so that all the parameters/files parses correctly.

Please also refer to the launch file for the urdf_tutorials at:
https://github.com/ros/urdf_tutorial/blob/ros2/launch/display.launch.py

Comment: Yes, but I was using urdf_tutorial(sudo apt install ros-rolling-urdf-tutorial)’s launch file as I was just learning the ways of urdf. For next time I’ll be specific bout the problem. It turns out if I turn off the network it works fine even on arm64 chips